# Do 2 commands with the "for" command in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, rename

I wanted to make a batch script that would go into the folder %~dp0\Playlists\%list% and rename each .mp3 file in there to the next number.
For example, the top file would be renamed to "1" and the second would be renamed to "2". I looked everywhere but I couldn't find out why my code wouldn't work.

```
set playnmbr=0
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "%~dp0\Playlists\%list%"`) do (
rename %~dp0\Playlists\%list%\%%f %playnmbr%.mp3
set /A playnmbr=%playnmbr%+1
)
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Can you show me a refined version of my code with it? I added "SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion" just before it and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (as npocmaka wrote):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set playnmbr=0
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "%~dp0\Playlists\%list%"`) do (
    rename %~dp0\Playlists\%list%\%%f !playnmbr!.mp3
    set /A playnmbr=!playnmbr!+1
)
```

Also, `%list%` is not defined in your code.

Comment: Just a suggestion: change `set /A playnmbr=!playnmbr!+1` by `set /A playnmbr+=1`